# Xpage Custom Controls not displaying in edit mode

Tags: xpages

I have an xPage with a couple custom controls.  One CC nested inside the other.   When I place the xPage into edit mode the innermost CC does not swich to edit mode but it's containing CC does. What am I missing here?  The edit button is just a simple 'change document mode' action.

xPage Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:button value="Edit" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="document1"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
        </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xc:Outer></xc:Outer>
</xp:view>
```

Outer Custom Control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:table style="border-color:rgb(0,64,128);border-style:solid;border-width:medium">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label id="label1" value="Outer CC"></xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button value="Edit" id="button1">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
                <xp:button value="Submit" id="button2"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Outer Field" id="label2"></xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                    value="#{document1.FieldOuter}">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xc:Inner></xc:Inner></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Inner Custom Control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:table style="border-color:rgb(255,128,0);border-style:solid;border-width:medium">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Inner CC" id="label1"></xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button value="Edit" id="button1"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="document1"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
    </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
                <xp:button value="Submit" id="button2"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Field Inner" id="label2"></xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.FieldInner}"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Do they use the same datasource? Do you have a readonly xp:panel?

Comment: Make a sample, post it here

Comment: Is the innermost CC set to readonly?

Comment: Innermost CC is not set to read only.  Both CC's use the same datasource (mapped to the same db form).If I place an edit button on the inner CC (so there are two edit buttons on the page) the inner CC edit button does place that CC into edit mode.  The outer CC edit button only placing the outer CC into edit mode.  I'll work on a sample.

Comment: I've added some sample code above.  Using this, the edit buttons only work on their own scope.  xPages edit button doesn't place into edit mode any CC, outer CC edit button only edits outer CC and inner CC edit button only edits inner CC.  All three use the same datasource.  I can make it work in my situation because I don't really need the inner CC, but I'd like to understand the mechanics of this.

Answer (score 1):

Each Custom Control and your xpage all have a datasource but they have the same name and are bound to the same document as they are not ignoring request params.  The Change Document Mode button is looking for the first datasource on the page with the var specified and changing that to read only and hence only updating for fields that are bound to that datasource.  I would ensure you only have a single datasource with the same name and work it that way.